Devika UI not running on Bun server
enter image description here
I installed all dependencies yet the devika ui is not showing up. help
I opened a terminal and started bun server , it showed server online
Then i opened another terminal and ran devika.py , it showed devika is running
still localserver is a blank screen
p.s - i have seen youtube tutorials where when they run devika.py , a brief message indicating flask comes but it didn't come in my case
